# Can't authenticate with a secondary account for new Mongo database

Tags: mongodb

For some reason, I cannot authenticate with a new user in a new database in a Mongo instance that I'm currently connected with using another account on an old database.  For instance, I can login with "dbadmin" to "db1" fine, but when I created a new database "newdb" I cannot login with a newly created account.

Here are the steps I followed to create the account:

> mongo mongodev01.example.com/admin -u admin -p [password]

This admin account has the following roles: userAdminAnyDatabase, dbAdminAnyDatabase, and readWriteAnyDatabase.

At the DB prompt I issued the following:

> use newdb
>
> db.createUser({"user":"newadmin", "pwd": "asdfqwer", "roles":["readWrite"]})

I used `show users` and saw the account created in this database with the readWrite role:

```
> show users
{
    "_id" : "newdb.newadmin",
    "user" : "newadmin",
    "db" : "newdb",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "newdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then restarted the `mongod` instance but when I tried to log in remotely (local works fine), I got "authorization failed" even though I had cut-and-pasted the password I used to create the user in the first place.  Any ideas?

```
$ mongo mameteordev01.example.com/db1 -u dbamdin -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
Enter password:
connecting to: mamongodev01.example.com/db1
> exit
bye

$ mongo mamongodev01.example.com/newdb -u newadmin -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
Enter password:
connecting to: mamongodev01.example.com/newdb
2014-11-06T20:32:25.676-0800 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `newadmin` has permission to `newdb` only. You should use the option `--authenticationDatabase newdb` when logging in:

```
mongo mongodev01.example.com/newdb -u newadmin -p asdfqwer
```

or

```
mongo mongodev01.example.com -u newadmin -p asdfqwer --authenticationDatabase newdb
```

Comment: Actually, I can login locally using this approach locally, but see the output above when I try remotely.

Comment: Oh jeez...I'm logging into wrong server.  Need to step away from keyboard. :/